# Tableau does not get data by connecting to SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, tableau-api

I am using `Tableau 10.3` to connect to a stored procedure (SP) in a SQL Server (2012) Database. Tableau can connect to any regular tables in the database when I drag one to the data course canvas.

However, when I drag a SP to the data source canvas, `Tableau` does not get any data from that SP. The SP is as simple as below (for testing purposes):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Tableau_testOnTableRptCat]
as
begin
  select * from ReportCategories
end
```

I am a new comer here, sorry for any thing I may miss for asking a tech question.

Comment: this might help https://community.tableau.com/ideas/3775

Comment: Try adding SET NOCOUNT ON

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the SQL Server SP constraints pasted below and found on this [page](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_stored_procedures.html)? Not sure if your case fits but its a start.

> Stored Procedure Constraints for SQL Server Databases
>
> The following constraints apply for stored procedures on SQL Server >databases.
>
> If the result set for a stored procedure contains columns of type IMAGE >or TEXT, the stored procedure will fail with an "Incorrect syntax" error >message.
>
> If the total width of the result set (number of bytes in each row) >exceeds 8060, the stored procedure fails. This can occur with very wide >tables (hundreds of columns) or with tables having large text columns, >intended to hold thousands of characters of text.
>
> Tableau does not display stored procedures from schema "sys".
>
> If the user does not provide a value for one or more parameters that the >procedure requires, Tableau displays a SQL Server database error in the form >"The procedure requires a value for parameter @x but one was not provided."
>
> Stored procedures that contain multiple queries should follow the >guidelines listed in Notes on Stored Procedures (above).
>
> Tableau Desktop does not support the Microsoft SQL Server TIME data >type. When fields of this type are included in a stored procedure on a >Microsoft SQL Server database Tableau Desktop will not import them.